# Prove that $ d'(\{a_{n}\} , \{b_{n} \}) = \operatorname{lub}\{|a_{n}-b_{n}| \mid n \in P\}$ defines a metric on $l^{\infty}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that  $ d'(\{a_{n} \} , \{ b_{n} \}) = \operatorname{lub}\{|a_{n}-b_{n}| \mid n \in P\}$ defines a metric on $l^{\infty}$ Where $l^{\infty}$ is the set of bounded sequences and $P$ is the natural numbers.

I am having trouble proving the triangle inequality portion. Since the sequences are bounded I know that the least upper bounds are finite but that's it at this point. Thanks

Comment: On an unrelated note, the notation in this post reminds me of one of Spivak's many chatty moments in Calculus: (p. 120)
"The term supremum of $A$ is synonymous and has one advantage. It abbreviates quite nicely to $\sup A$ and saves us from the abbreviation $\text{lub} A$ (which is nevertheless used by some authors)."

Comment: $P$ must be the strangest way I have ever seen for writing $\mathbb N$. :-)

Comment: Haha yeah.It's just in this book im looking at with P for some reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$, and $\{c_n\}$ be sequences. Then we want to show $$d'(\{a_n\},\{c_n\})\leq d'(\{a_n\},\{b_n\})+d'(\{b_n\},\{c_n\}).$$ Note that the least upper bound is the supremum, denoted $\sup$, so we have $d'(\{a_n\},\{c_n\})=\sup|a_n-c_n|$. Now, observe that
\begin{align}
\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|a_n-b_n+b_n-c_n|&\leq\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}(|a_n-b_n|+|b_n-c_n|)\\
&\leq\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|a_n-b_n|+\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|b_n-c_n|\tag{1}\\
&=d'(\{a_n\},\{b_n\})+d'(\{b_n\},\{c_n\}).
\end{align}

Note that $(1)$ is true since $|a_n-b_n|\leq\sup|a_n-b_n|$ and $|b_n-c_n|\leq\sup|b_n-c_n|$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, hence $$|a_n-b_n|+|b_n-c_n|\leq\sup|a_n-b_n|+\sup|b_n-c_n|.$$Thus, the right hand side is an upper bound, thus it is at least as great as the least upper bound. This proves the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha=\langle a_n:n\in P\rangle,\beta=\langle b_n:n\in P\rangle,\gamma=\langle c_n:n\in P\rangle\in\ell^\infty$, and suppose, hoping for a contradiction, that $d\,'(\alpha,\gamma)>d\,'(\alpha,\beta)+d\,'(\beta,\gamma)$. Then there is an $n\in P$ such that

$$\begin{align*}
|a_n-c_n|&>d\,'(\alpha,\beta)+d\,'(\beta,\gamma)\\
&=\sup_{k\in P}|a_k-b_k|+\sup_{k\in P}|b_k-c_k|\\
&\ge\sup_{k\in P}\big(|a_k-b_k|+|b_k-c_k|\big)\\
&\ge\sup_{k\in P}|a_k-c_k|\;,
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

which is absurd.

Note that this need not have been organized as a proof by contradiction: the calculation in $(1)$, read from the bottom up and ignoring the top line, is a direct proof. Contradiction is simply a very natural way to start when you’re comparing a supremum with something; when you don’t immediately see a better approach, it’s worth a try, because it typically gives you more to work with.